# @{item().TableName} only gives first part of string

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have database from which I take nvarchar to lookup. Then I transport it to foreach. My problem is that when I use @item().TableName in dataset properties as value it works fine but when I use @{item().TableName} in query it takes only first part of it. So when it is "Receipt Header" I only get "Receipt"

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide a snip or complete expression you are using in the query?

Comment: @select MAX([Creation Date]) as NewWatermarkvalue from @{item().sourceSchema}.@{item().TableName}

Comment: try to use concat function `@concat('select MAX([Creation Date]) as NewWatermarkvalue from ',item().sourceSchema,'.[',item().TableName),']')`

Comment: Glad it worked! posting it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the table name within the square brackets `'[]'` if it contains space or any special characters and use `concat()` function when combining constants with variables in the expression.

**Query:**

```
@concat('select MAX([Creation Date]) as NewWatermarkvalue from ',item().sourceSchema,'.[',item().TableName),']')
```